# Convert python sequence with multiple datatypes to tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, types, tuples

I'm using TensorFlow r1.7 and python3.6.5. I am also very new to TensorFlow, so I'd like easy to read explanations if possible.

I'm trying to convert my input data into a dataset of tensors with this function `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`. I pass my tuple with mixed datatypes into this function. However, when running my code I get this error: `ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor`.

I want to know why I am receiving this error, and how I can convert my data to a dataset of tensors even with mixed datatypes.

Here's a printout of the top 5 entries in my tuple.

```
(13501, 2, None, 51, '2232', 'S35', '734.72', 'CLA', '240', 1035, 2060, 1252, 1182, 10, '967.28', '338.50', None, 14, 102, 3830)
(15124, 2, None, 57, '2641', 'S35', '234.80', 'DDA', '240', 743, 1597, 4706, 156, 0, None, None, None, 3, 27, 981)
(40035, 2, None, None, '21', 'K00', '60.06', 'CHK', '520', 76, 1863, 12, None, 1, '85.06', '25.00', None, 1, 5, 245)
(42331, 3, None, 62, '121', 'S50', '1859.01', 'ACT', '420', 952, 1583, 410, 255, 0, None, None, None, 6, 117, 1795)
(201721, 3, None, 42, '2472', 'S35', '1413.84', 'CLA', '350', 868, 1746, 963, 264, 0, None, None, None, 18, 65, 4510)
```

As you can see, I have a mix of integers, floats, and strings in my input data.

Here is a traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/miikey101/Documents/Khalen_Case_Loader/tensorflow/k_means/k_means.py", line 10, in prepare_dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dm_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 222, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1017, in __init__
    for i, t in enumerate(nest.flatten(tensors))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1017, in <listcomp>
    for i, t in enumerate(nest.flatten(tensors))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 950, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 185, in constant
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 131, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, context=handle, device=device, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In tensorflow you can't have a tensor with more than one data type.

Quoting the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors#data_types):

> It is not possible to have a tf.Tensor with more than one data type. It is possible, however, to serialize arbitrary data structures as strings and store those in tf.Tensors.

Hence a workaround could be to create a tensor with data type `tf.String` and, on the occurrence, cast the field to the desired data type

Comment: I see, thank you. I converted all my strings to integer representations, then all the integers to floats and I was able to successfully convert the data into tensors.

Answer (score 1):

You want a tensor for each of your features (columns). Only if it's a multi-dimensional feature (like an image, a video, list of strings, vector) would you have more dimensions in the tensor and even then they would all have the same datatype.

`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` will accept your input as a dictionary of lists (key is the name of the feature, value is a list of the values in that feature), or as a list of lists. I can't remember if it eats Pandas dataframes but if it doesn't you can easily convert it to a dictionary `df.to_dict()`.

However, you can't input `None` values. You will have to find some value for those before converting into a tensor. Classic approaches to that is median value, zero value, most common value, "missing"/"unknown" value for strings or categories, or imputation.