# Fitting Keras Sequential Model gives ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have the following array of lists (actors per movie):

```py
partial_x_train_actors=array([list([b'victor mclaglen', b'jon hall', b'frances farmer', b'olympe bradna', b'gene lockhart', b'douglass dumbrille', b'francis ford', b'ben welden', b'abner biberman', b'pedro de cordoba', b'rudy robles', b'bobby stone', b'nellie duran', b'james flavin', b'nina campana']),
       list([b'jessica biel', b'ben barnes', b'kristin scott thomas', b'colin firth', b'kimberley nixon', b'katherine parkinson', b'kris marshall', b'christian brassington', b'charlotte riley', b'jim mcmanus', b'pip torrens', b'jeremy hooton', b'joanna bacon', b'maggie hickey', b'georgie glen']),
       list([b'gr\xc3\xa9gori derang\xc3\xa8re', b'anouk grinberg', b'aur\xc3\xa9lien recoing', b'niels arestrup', b'yann collette', b'laure duthilleul', b'david assaraf', b'pascal demolon', b'jean-baptiste iera', b'richard sammel', b'vincent crouzet', b'fred epaud', b'pascal elso', b'nicolas giraud', b'micha\xc3\xabl abiteboul']),
       ...,
       list([b'jason schwartzman', b'mickey rourke', b'brittany murphy', b'john leguizamo', b'patrick fugit', b'mena suvari', b'chloe hunter', b'elisa bocanegra', b'julia mendoza', b'china chow', b'nicholas gonzalez', b'debbie harry', b'josh peck', b'charlotte ayanna', b'eric roberts']),
       list([b'fred kirschenmann', b'daniel salatin', b'joel salatin', b'paul willis', b'chuck wirtz']),
       list([b'jan sebastian', b'tray loren', b'paul muzzcat', b'brad koepenick', b'jerry armstrong', b'ben sebastian', b'reyn hubbard', b'levita gros', b'betty flemming', b'randolph parro', b'susan serigny', b'keith gros', b'rocky dugas', b'sid larrwiere', b'jocelyn boudreaux'])],
      dtype=object)
```

Since I want to use that as an input to a Keras model I have to convert the array of lists to an array of arrays. To do this I am running the following code, taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760510/converting-array-of-lists-to-keras-input)

```py
partial_x_train_actors_array=[]

for i in range(len(partial_x_train_actors)):
    
    partial_x_train_actors_array.append(np.array(list(x for x in partial_x_train_actors[i])))

partial_x_train_actors_array = np.asarray(partial_x_train_actors_array)=
type(partial_x_train_actors_array[0])
```

So now I get this:

```py
array([array([b'victor mclaglen', b'jon hall', b'frances farmer',
       b'olympe bradna', b'gene lockhart', b'douglass dumbrille',
       b'francis ford', b'ben welden', b'abner biberman',
       b'pedro de cordoba', b'rudy robles', b'bobby stone',
       b'nellie duran', b'james flavin', b'nina campana'], dtype='|S18'),
       array([b'jessica biel', b'ben barnes', b'kristin scott thomas',
       b'colin firth', b'kimberley nixon', b'katherine parkinson',
       b'kris marshall', b'christian brassington', b'charlotte riley',
       b'jim mcmanus', b'pip torrens', b'jeremy hooton', b'joanna bacon',
       b'maggie hickey', b'georgie glen'], dtype='|S21'),
       array([b'gr\xc3\xa9gori derang\xc3\xa8re', b'anouk grinberg',
       b'aur\xc3\xa9lien recoing', b'niels arestrup', b'yann collette',
       b'laure duthilleul', b'david assaraf', b'pascal demolon',
       b'jean-baptiste iera', b'richard sammel', b'vincent crouzet',
       b'fred epaud', b'pascal elso', b'nicolas giraud',
       b'micha\xc3\xabl abiteboul'], dtype='|S19'),
       ...,
       array([b'jason schwartzman', b'mickey rourke', b'brittany murphy',
       b'john leguizamo', b'patrick fugit', b'mena suvari',
       b'chloe hunter', b'elisa bocanegra', b'julia mendoza',
       b'china chow', b'nicholas gonzalez', b'debbie harry', b'josh peck',
       b'charlotte ayanna', b'eric roberts'], dtype='|S17'),
       array([b'fred kirschenmann', b'daniel salatin', b'joel salatin',
       b'paul willis', b'chuck wirtz'], dtype='|S17'),
       array([b'jan sebastian', b'tray loren', b'paul muzzcat',
       b'brad koepenick', b'jerry armstrong', b'ben sebastian',
       b'reyn hubbard', b'levita gros', b'betty flemming',
       b'randolph parro', b'susan serigny', b'keith gros', b'rocky dugas',
       b'sid larrwiere', b'jocelyn boudreaux'], dtype='|S17')],
      dtype=object)
```

But neither this is sufficient to get away from the type of the input Tensor, since I get this error:

```py
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

**My model fit process**

```py
# import the pre-trained model
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

# create the neural network structure
model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="English_Google_News_130GB_witout_OOV_tokens")
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(i, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(neural_network_parameters['l2_regularization']),
                                        activation=neural_network_parameters['dense_activation']))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(neural_network_parameters['dropout_rate']))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(y_val.shape[1], 

activation=neural_network_parameters['output_activation']))
        
#model.name("English Google News 130GB witout OOV tokens")
print(model.summary())
        
#instantiate Optimizer
optimizer = optimizer_adam_v2(len(partial_x_train_actors_array), validation_split_ratio, i)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
              metrics=[neural_network_parameters['model_metric']])

plot_model(model, to_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_three\\network_structure_english_google_news_without_OOV_model_{0}.png'.format(version_data_control)))

history = model.fit([partial_x_train_features, partial_x_train_plot, partial_x_train_actors_array, partial_x_train_reviews],
                        partial_y_train,
                        steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((len(partial_x_train_actors_array)*0.8)//16)),
                        epochs=100,
                        batch_size=16,
                        validation_split=0.2
                        verbose=0,
                        callbacks=callback("english_google_news_without_oovtokens", model))
```

[EDIT] - 04.07.2020

I would like to add that I have done the padding on sequences for another experiment and the actor's list that presented above is transformed to list below

```py
partial_x_train_actors=array([[ 2024,  3228,   451, ..., 18119,     0,     0],
       [ 3230,  7889, 12357, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [20001, 20001, 20001, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [ 6887, 20001, 15352, ..., 20001, 20001, 20001],
       [10206, 20001,  3426, ..., 20001,     0,     0],
       [ 2969,  5903,   447, ...,     0,     0,     0]])
```

However, when I apply this list in the .fit() of the neural network I get the following error

```py
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_4_input to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (39192, 17)
```

(39192, 17) is the shape of the actors array

[EDIT 2] - 05.07.2020

**Trial 1** (failed)

Based on some proposals on the answers provided I tried to change input shape of the hub.Keraslayer:

```
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[len(y_train)], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
```

I made it equal to my training_input length #39192 data per actor, plot, features, reviews.

Error produced:
[image]
From the error, I can guess that the input_shape should be []?

**Trial 2** (failed)

```py
#list of actors (training data) tensors
actors_training_tensors=np.array([tf.convert_to_tensor(partial_x_train_actors[i]) for i in range(len(partial_x_train_actors))])
actors_testing_tensors=np.array([tf.convert_to_tensor(x_val_actors[i]) for i in range(len(x_val_actors))])
```

Error again:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).
```

I transformed the input list of actors to tensor. Note that only the actor's list has problems because they are stored as names in a list [[name1, name2, name3]]. I had no problem neither with plot, features, or reviews inputs because they are saved as a list of corpus.

**Trial 3** (failed)

Based on the comments I used the data API likewise:

```py
data_tf=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([partial_x_train_features, partial_x_train_plot, partial_x_train_actors_array, partial_x_train_reviews])
```

Again I got an error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.
```

So I searched about it, and I figured out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824872/convert-python-sequence-with-multiple-datatypes-to-tensor) and the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#data_types),
I did the following change, (added tf.constant):

```py
data_tf=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([tf.constant(partial_x_train_features), tf.constant(partial_x_train_plot), tf.constant(partial_x_train_actors_array), tf.constant(partial_x_train_reviews)])
```

Moreover, it seems that I cannot convert a NumPy array of strings to a Tensor of floats. Probably here is where the padding of sequences plays an important role. However, if you follow [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_text_classification) of a tensorflow article from which I got the idea, you will notice that the user gives as input only byte strings and not padded sequences.

*Please note that a solution to all of this, is just to flatten the list of actors by using the " ".join() command. However, the actors would be just a text of names and not a separate name. Even though it works, I think that for better results the actors should be given as separate names because a Neural Network cannot distinguish names on its own.*

[INPUT DATA FOR DEBUGGING - ISSUE REPLICATION]

In case someone wants to replicate and debug the problem, below I represents my 4 input layers (sample of data) and [the article from Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_text_classification) that I have followed.

Here is the Issue's [GitHub link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41109) with the question posted. As it seems when I run the code locally everything looks fine apart from the EarlyStopping error presented in the GitHub issue attached. I will re-check the data that I use, because the data provided in the GitHub link are the proper data to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving this error as you are trying to convert the `numpy.ndarry` to Tensor.
In short, your arrays are of different length and that is not accepted while converting it to Tensor.

What you have to do is make your `x`'s of the same length and the `y`'s of the same length.

There are several ways to achieve this. Based on the code you provided you can use something like below: The below code is pseudo-code and it just to demonstrate that you need arrays of equal length.

```
for i in range(len(partial_x_train_actors)):
    
    partial_x_train_actors_array.append(np.array(list(x for x in partial_x_train_actors[i:5]))) # for example getting only 5 elements from the list, you can change as per your need
```

The other way is to use the `tf.data` API using [Generators](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) to convert your dataset to `tf.data.Dataset` and then use the `tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch` to padded the batch to make your dataset of equal length. Here is the API [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch).

[After the Question Edit]
Your second problem with the array, shape is due to the fact that you have coded the input shape to [].

```
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
```

Due to this reason you receive the error that your input layer expects 1 dimension but received (39192,17). As your in your `model.fit()` you use `x` as

```
[partial_x_train_features, partial_x_train_plot, partial_x_train_actors_array, partial_x_train_reviews]
```

I will suggest you change input_shape according to your dataset and not [].

If you still face any issue, I will request to post a Github link so that I can debug to see the actual issue.

**[05/07/2020] - Update**

I have debugged your code, made some changes in your input data, and made it to work. I have used the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` API to concatenate your data. I have made changes to your loss function and the optimizer so that I can debug. You can make changes according to your needs. Also, make sure that the inputs `partial_x_train_reviews`, `partial_x_train_plot` and `partial_x_train_features` should look something like this. But if you want to keep it the old way change the `def generator():` method accordingly. Do let me know how it goes. I will recommend that if your issue is resolved to do hit upvote also next time provide a code that somebody can readily debug and not make lots of changes to make it work. I hope the answer serves you well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

# Train variables
partial_x_train_features = [
    [b'south pago pago victor mclaglen jon hall frances farmer olympe bradna gene lockhart douglass dumbrille francis ford ben welden abner biberman pedro cordoba rudy robles bobby stone nellie duran james flavin nina campana alfred e green treasure hunt adventure adventure'],
    [b'easy virtue jessica biel ben barnes kristin scott thomas colin firth kimberley nixon katherine parkinson kris marshall christian brassington charlotte riley jim mcmanus pip torrens jeremy hooton joanna bacon maggie hickey georgie glen stephan elliott young englishman marry glamorous american brings home meet parent arrive like blast future blow entrenched british stuffiness window comedy romance'],
    [b'fragments antonin gregori derangere anouk grinberg aurelien recoing niels arestrup yann collette laure duthilleul david assaraf pascal demolon jean baptiste iera richard sammel vincent crouzet fred epaud pascal elso nicolas giraud michael abiteboul gabriel le bomin psychiatrist probe mind traumatized soldier attempt unlock secret drove gentle deeply disturbed world war veteran edge insanity drama war'],
    [b'milka film taboos milka elokuva tabuista irma huntus leena suomu matti turunen eikka lehtonen esa niemela sirkka metsasaari tauno lehtihalmes ulla tapaninen toivo tuomainen hellin auvinen salmi rauni mollberg small finnish lapland community milka innocent year old girl live mother miss dead father prays god love haymaking employ drama'],
    [b'sleeping car david naughton judie aronson kevin mccarthy jeff conaway dani minnick ernestine mercer john carl buechler gary brockette steve lundquist billy stevenson michael scott bicknell david coburn nicole hansen tiffany million robert ruth douglas curtis jason david naughton move abandon train car resurrect vicious ghost landlady dead husband mister near fatal encounter comedy horror']]

partial_x_train_plot = [[b'treasure hunt adventure'],
                        [b'young englishman marry glamorous american brings home meet parent arrive like blast future blow entrenched british stuffiness window'],
                        [b'psychiatrist probe mind traumatized soldier attempt unlock secret drove gentle deeply disturbed world war veteran edge insanity'],
                        [b'small finnish lapland community milka innocent year old girl live mother miss dead father prays god love haymaking employ'],
                        [b'jason david naughton move abandon train car resurrect vicious ghost landlady dead husband mister near fatal encounter']]

partial_x_train_actors_array = [[b'victor mclaglen', b'jon hall', b'frances farmer',
                                 b'olympe bradna', b'gene lockhart', b'douglass dumbrille',
                                 b'francis ford', b'ben welden', b'abner biberman',
                                 b'pedro de cordoba', b'rudy robles', b'bobby stone',
                                 b'nellie duran', b'james flavin', b'nina campana'],
                                [b'jessica biel', b'ben barnes', b'kristin scott thomas',
                                 b'colin firth', b'kimberley nixon', b'katherine parkinson',
                                 b'kris marshall', b'christian brassington', b'charlotte riley',
                                 b'jim mcmanus', b'pip torrens', b'jeremy hooton', b'joanna bacon',
                                 b'maggie hickey', b'georgie glen'],
                                [b'gregori derangere', b'anouk grinberg', b'aurelien recoing',
                                 b'niels arestrup', b'yann collette', b'laure duthilleul',
                                 b'david assaraf', b'pascal demolon', b'jean-baptiste iera',
                                 b'richard sammel', b'vincent crouzet', b'fred epaud',
                                 b'pascal elso', b'nicolas giraud', b'michael abiteboul'],
                                [b'irma huntus', b'leena suomu', b'matti turunen',
                                 b'eikka lehtonen', b'esa niemela', b'sirkka metsasaari',
                                 b'tauno lehtihalmes', b'ulla tapaninen', b'toivo tuomainen',
                                 b'hellin auvinen-salmi'],
                                [b'david naughton', b'judie aronson', b'kevin mccarthy',
                                 b'jeff conaway', b'dani minnick', b'ernestine mercer',
                                 b'john carl buechler', b'gary brockette', b'steve lundquist',
                                 b'billy stevenson', b'michael scott-bicknell', b'david coburn',
                                 b'nicole hansen', b'tiffany million', b'robert ruth']]

partial_x_train_reviews = [
    [b'edward small take director alfred e green cast crew uncommonly attractive brilliant assemblage south sea majority curiously undersung piece location far stylize date goldwyn hurricane admittedly riddle cliche formula package visual technical excellence scarcely matter scene stop heart chiseled adonis jon hall porcelain idol frances farmer outline profile s steam background volcano romantic closeup level defies comparison edward small film typically string frame individual work art say outdid do workhorse composer edward ward song score year prior work universal stun phantom opera'],
    [b'jessica biel probably best know virtuous good girl preacher kid mary camden heaven get tackle classic noel coward role early play easy virtue american interloper english aristocratic family unsettle family matriarch kristin scott thomas noel coward write upper class twit pretension wit keep come kind adopt way adopt oscar wilde george bernard shaw kid grow poverty way talent entertain upper class take coward heart felt modern progressive generally term social trend whittakers easy virtue kind aristocrat anybody like hang party invite noel entertain amelia earhart aviation jessica biel character auto race young widow detroit area course area motor car auto race fresh win monte carlo win young ben barnes heir whittaker estates lot land debt barnes bring biel home family mortify classless american way sense recognize class distinction thing get rid title nobility aristocrats story scott thomas dominate family try desperately estate husband colin firth serve world war horror do probably horror trench war slaughter fact class distinction tend melt combat biel kind like wife rule whittaker roost scandal past threatens disrupt barnes biel marriage form crux story turn fact end really viewer figure eventually happen second film adaption easy virtue silent film direct young alfred hitchcock easy virtue actually premier america london star great american stage actress jane cowl guess coward figure american heroine best american theatergoer british one version easy virtue direct flawlessly stephen elliot fine use period music noel coward cole porter end credit really mock upper class coward tradition play going gets tough tough going believe elliott try say class especially one right stuff course obligatory fox hunt upper class indulge oscar wilde say unspeakable uneatable chance younger generation expose noel coward worth see'],
    [b'saw night eurocine event movie european country show day european city hear le bomin barely hear derangere la chambre des officiers fortunately surprise discover great talent unknown large audience derangere absolutely astonish play character antonin verset victim post wwi trauma live trouble scene endure month war cast excellent great work cinematography offer really nice shot great landscape stun face edit really subtile bit memory make sense story minute movie show real chill ww archive action flick like sensitive psychologic movie really think absolutely recommend les fragments d antonin let le bomin'],
    [b'rauni mollberg earth sinful song favorite foreign film establish director major talent film festival circuit get amazing followup milka base work novelist timo mukka till worthy major dvd exposure unlike kaurismaki bros follow double handedly create tongue cheek deadpan finnish film style fan world mollberg commit naturalistic approach film overflow nature life lust earthiness find scandi cinema mainly work famous talent swede vilgot sjoman curious yellow fame director film tabu title imply mollberg effort quite effective sidestep fully treat screen theme incest making adult character father figure real blood relate daddy applies usual merely step father gimmick use countless time american movie incest work matti turunen kristus perkele translate christ devil really common law step dad underage milka beautiful offbeat fashion young girl portray shot irma huntus bring screen sexiness bergman harriet andersson decade earlier create international success summer monika sawdust tinsel imagine actress milka role shame do pursue act career afterward completing strong line leena suomu earth mother type confines act narrow emotional range prove solid rock crucial role bookended spectacularly beautiful shot birch wood winter virtually black white visually color presence milka film quickly develop nature theme presence strange click beak bird talisman early scene milka handyman turunen frolicking naked lake emerge oh natural sex play year old milka man result tastefully shoot intimacy imply ejaculation set trouble come religious aspect remote farm community heavily stress especially enjoy motif spiritual guidance cantor malmstrom quality anti stereotypical play eikka lehtonen instead rigid cruel turn care milka illegitimate baby bear strong romance turunen stud continue service mom woman neighborhood present utterly natural viewer position watch ethnographic exercise moralistic tale powerful technique milka frequently speak directly camera viewer forceful monologue bear crisp sound record sound nature include rain constant motif make milka engross experience view film subtitle knowledge finnish lapp recall best silent era classic direction strong convey dramatic content theme way transcend language kudos mollberg talented cinematographer job work remain obscurity ripe rediscovery'],
    [b'wonder horror film write woody allen wannabe come like check imaginatively direct typical enjoyable haunt place premise solid makeup effect good job major flaw dialogue overload cheeky wisecrack witticisms sample want scary shopping ex wife hit mark deliver inappropriate moment hero battle evil ghost']]

partial_y_train = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]  # multilabel classification



# Using generator for creating the dataset.
def generator():
    for i in range(0, len(partial_y_train)):
        # creates x's and y's for the dataset.
        yield b''.join((partial_x_train_features[i] + partial_x_train_plot[i] + partial_x_train_actors_array[i] +
             partial_x_train_reviews[i])), partial_y_train[i]



dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.string, tf.int64),
                                         (tf.TensorShape(None), tf.TensorShape([17])))

dataset = dataset.batch(1)

for i, j in dataset.take(5):
    print(i)
    print(j)

# import the pre-trained model
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

# create the neural network structure
model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="English_Google_News_130GB_witout_OOV_tokens")
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='softmax'))

# model.name("English Google News 130GB witout OOV tokens")
print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the code snippet attached does not work as expected. Because it results to an array of lists with not a fixed size.  Secondly, I cannot resolve the issue with the tf.data API. Can you post an example that would solve this with the code attached? ....I try this ```dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(partial_x_train_actors_array[0])``` but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I want also to add that I had done the padding earlier for a different model. But now when I use the already padded actors list I get this error ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_4_input to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (39192, 17)```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it serves you well. For dataset API, you can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([partial_x_train_features, partial_x_train_plot, partial_x_train_actors_array, partial_x_train_reviews])`.

Comment: Prateek Bhatt please check my latest update. I uploaded the code on GitHub and I have run it locally successfully. It seems that maybe because I import many libraries keras got an unexpected import. Or probably the numpy arrays I used in my first run weren't the correct format. Please check my issue on GitHub because now EarlyStopping has a problem.

Comment: I just updated my answer and made the code working. Too late I guess. I will suggest creating a new issue for your EarlyStopping problem so that it can be looked in isolation to other problems.

Comment: Yeah I can create a new issue...You mean in StackOverflow or in GitHub?...Also I run your code (just copy-paste) and got the following error ```ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type. Received input: <BatchDataset shapes: (<unknown>, (None, 17)), types: (tf.string, tf.int64)>, batch_size: 1```

Comment: It is weird, on my box the code is running without issues, are you sure you are running the code alone without any other code?

Comment: If you may, please copy paste the code pasted on GitHub and let me now any insights about the EarlyStopping rounds. About the initial issue probably my data format were wrong (dont know why but with the data on GitHub everything worked, at least the training start') .

Comment: Yeah I get the same error. I opened a new Jupyter Notebook kernel to be sure.

Comment: You could try the fit API without the batch_size. something like this `history = model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=10)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217267/discussion-between-niksp-and-prateek-bhatt).

Comment: Prateek please re-join the room I have a question :)

Comment: Hey Prateek, wanna talk about something I found on this answer you posted?... I made it to work and thanks for the data generator way. However, I have a couple of questions to ask you. Are you online?

Comment: Hey @niksp. I am not available atm. I will be available tomorrow at 18:00 (CENTRAL EUROPEAN TIME). Then we can talk about your issues.

Comment: Prateek ping me when you are available at around 18:00 (CET)

Comment: I will need few minutes. Msg you once I am online.

Comment: Hey Prateek are you free now? Please go to my colab notebook  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-hRZCC2WDkGLrl8kaMIw6LUDBnC4LHSh/view?usp=sharing so we can continue from there

Comment: Hey Prateek if you are free today evening or during the day, I would be happy to talk. Very briefly, if you have seen my colab notebook I am using the data generator object of tensorflow. However to create the training, test and validation dataset I use the command dataset.batch(1) and I was wandering if this command utilizes the full potential of my dataset or I am missing some data. For example dataset.batch(100) what's the difference? (PS I followed the solution you posted here and worked perfectly but the use of dataset.batch(1) takes into account the whole dataset?)

Comment: Okay, NickSp, let us talk today evening. Just in short `.batch` API just creates batches for you. If you want to make your input pipeline more efficient you should use `cache` and `prefetch` API's. You can find both the API's here - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Comment: Prateek ping me whenever you are free :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218230/discussion-between-prateek-bhatt-and-niksp).

Comment: Hey Prateek I have a question to ask you. If I use a tensor that has the information of 4 input in one string likewise we greater 1 string with the generator API, is it the same to feed a neural network with 4 inputs separately than having all the 4 inputs as string?...So in one case we will have model.fit(dataset), while the other case will be model.fil([input 1, input 2, input 3, input 4]). Dataset API creates a unique string based on the input that you will give. But does we get different results? I hope my question was clear.

Comment: Hey @NikSp, we can speak tomorrow, you can directly contact me on gmail.

Comment: Hey @Prateek, are you free today to have a chat? Thanks in advance for the help. I figured out why the .from_generator() stops. Because the training runs out of data and tensorflow instructs me to use the repeat() method. But I don't know for how many time to use the repeat()...Like repeat(3) or repeat(10) is better. I thought of using a repeat(10000) like really high and let EarlyStopping to stop the training