# Python: Variable size changed after the return statement

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, dimensions

I am trying to use word2vec embedding for a text classification task. However, it is strange that the value returned from the `preprocess()` function is different from the moment just before it was returned. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
train_data = [   {'corrected': 'have a good day', 'father': 1},
         {'corrected': 'i suggest you see this movie', 'father': 1},
         {'corrected': 'The afternoon grew so glowering that in the sixth inning the arc lights were turned on--always a wan sight in the daytime, like the burning headlights of a funeral procession. Aided by the gloom, Fisher was slicing through the Sox rookies, and Williams did not come to bat in the seventh. He was second up in the eighth. This was almost certainly his last time to come to the plate in Fenway Park, and instead of merely cheering, as we had at his three previous appearances, we stood, all of us, and applauded.', 'father': 2},
         {'corrected': 'worse than any show', 'father': 1},
         {'corrected': 'nice movie, so love it', 'father': 2},
         {'corrected': "The day I picked my dog up from the pound was one of the happiest days of both of our lives. I had gone to the pound just a week earlier with the idea that I would just 'look' at a puppy. Of course, you can no more just look at those squiggling little faces so filled with hope and joy than you can stop the sun from setting in the evening. I knew within minutes of walking in the door that I would get a puppy… but it wasn't until I saw him that I knew I had found my puppy", 'father': 2}
    ]

train_data= pd.DataFrame(train_data)
```

```
# Load Pretrained Word2Vec
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-250/2")

def get_word_count(essay):
    """
    get the number of vocab in the essay
    """
    return len(essay)

def get_word2vec_enc(essays):
    """
    get word2vec value for each word in sentence.
    concatenate word in numpy array, so we can use it as RNN input
    """
    encoded = []
    for essay in essays:
        tokens = essay.split(" ")
        word2vec_embedding = embed(tokens)
        encoded.append(word2vec_embedding)
    return encoded

def get_padded_encoded_essays(encoded_essays):
    """
    for short essays, we prepend zero padding so all input to RNN has same length,
    for long essays, we truncate it to the first 250 words
    """
    padded_essays_encoding = []
    for enc_essay in encoded_essays:
        if get_word_count(enc_essay)> 250:
            enc_essay[:249]
        
        else:
            zero_padding_cnt = 250 - enc_essay.shape[0]
            pad = np.zeros((1, 250))
            for i in range(zero_padding_cnt):
                enc_essay = np.concatenate((pad, enc_essay), axis=0)
        padded_essays_encoding.append(enc_essay)
    return padded_essays_encoding

def ses_encode(ses):
    """
    return one hot encoding for Y value
    """
    if ses == 1: 
        return [1,0]  # for high ses
    else: 
        return [0,1]  # for low ses
    
def preprocess(df):
    """
    encode text value to numeric value
    """
 
    # encode words into word2vec
    essays = df['corrected'].tolist()
    print("essay length:" + str(len(essays)))

    
    encoded_essays = get_word2vec_enc(essays)
    padded_encoded_essays = get_padded_encoded_essays(encoded_essays)
    print("padded_encoded_essays length:" + str(len(padded_encoded_essays)))
    
    # encoded ses
    sess = df['father'].tolist()

    encoded_ses = [ses_encode(ses) for ses in sess]
    X = np.vstack(padded_encoded_essays)
    print("X length:" + str(len(X)))
    Y = np.vstack(encoded_ses)

    return X, Y
```

```
train_X, train_Y = preprocess(train_data)

len(train_X) # it returns 1500

len(train_Y) # it returns 6
```

When I call `train_X, train_Y = preprocess(train_data)`, three print statements are "essay length:6;
padded_encoded_essays length:6;
X length:1500". I don't know why `np.vstack()` changes the size. Is there a way keep the size same while let the code working without warnings (when I did not include `np.vstack()` , my code had [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815664/python-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor))?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code once `print("X length:" + str(len(essays)))` - wich is `len(essays)`  - outside you `print(len (X))` where `X` was retuned as `np.vstack(padded_encoded_essays))`  - why/what exactly is confusing when printing different things that then have different lenghts?  `essays != padded_encoded_essays`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you, you are right, and that was a typo. I updated my post, so my real question is "is there anything to substitute `np.vstack()` in order to keep the size same?"

Comment: And this change now invalidates the one and once upvoted answer that you got already. Do not move the target of your question ...

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are looking for the length of `essays`:

```py
print("X length:" + str(len(essays)))
```

But, `X` is defined as:

```py
X = np.vstack(padded_encoded_essays)
```

Perhaps thats the reason and you are simply printing the length of something and returning something else as `X`.

Comment: Thank you @ebarooni. It was a typo in my code, and I have updated my post. My real question is "is there anything to substitute np.vstack() in order to keep the size same?" Do you have any suggestions?